# How to properly mock my RestTemplate unit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

My current unit test using RestTemplate to reach a GET endpoint has a lot of hard-coded values. I would like to know if there's a better approach mocking the values and how to do it.
Currently it looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CarServiceTest {

    private final String uri = "https://cars.com/cars";
    private final String token = "xxx";

    private List<Car> carList;
    private Cars testCars;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarService carService;

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        carList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Car("car1")));
        testCars = new Cars(carList);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getCars() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
        headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                    RequestEntity.get(new URI(uri)).headers(headers).build(),
                                    Cars.class))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCars, HttpStatus.OK));

        Cars returnedCars = carService.getCars();

        // assertion
        Assert.assertEquals(testCars, returnedCars);

        // verify
        verify(restTemplate).exchange(RequestEntity
                                        .get(new URI(uri)).headers(headers).build(),
                                         Cars.class);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(restTemplate);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the initialization/mocking of the objects being used in the test. (**I'm currently using real URL and token in the tests**)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html).

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();

server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(uri))
    .andExpect(requestTo(uri))
    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
    .andRespond(withSuccess(new ObjectMapper()
        .writeValueAsString(cars), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBearerAuth(token);
headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

restTemplate.exchange(RequestEntity.get(new URI(uri)).headers(headers).build(), Cars.class))

server.verify();
```

You can setup the stub that you need and also verify that the calls you expected actually happened in a few lines of code and is much more clearer IMO.

Comment: What annotations you need to use when declaring variables?

Comment: It depends entirely on your test environment but if you are talking about annotations like `@Mock`, you don't need those anymore since spring does all the stubbing and verfying for you. You can read the documentation linked on the answer to know more.